# Remove useless .0 from txt files in bash

Tags: sed

How can I remove useless ".0" strings in a txt file of numbers?

If I have this file:

```
43.65 24.0 889.5 5.0
32.14 32.0 900.0 6.0
38.27 43.0 899.4 5.0
```

I want to get:

```
43.65 24 889.5 5
32.14 32 900 6
38.27 43 899.4 5
```

I tried: `sed 's|\.0 | |g'` but that obviously does not work with new lines and EOF.

Any suggestion without getting into python, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's,([0-9])\.0($| ),\1\2,g' file
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `([0-9])\.0($| )` - finds and captures into Group 1 a digit, then matches `.0`, and then matches and captures into Group 2 a space or end of string
- `\1\2` - replaces with Group 1 + Group 2 concatenated values
- `g`  - replaces all occurrences.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/BSfCwh):

```sh
s='43.65 24.0 889.5 5.0
32.14 32.0 900.0 6.0
38.27 43.0 899.4 5.0'
sed -E 's,([0-9])\.0($| ),\1\2,g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
43.65 24 889.5 5
32.14 32 900 6
38.27 43 899.4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\.0\b//g' file
```

Or

```
sed 's/\.0\>//g' file
```

Remove any period followed by a zero followed by a word boundary.